# Unable to get cuda available in Jupyter Notebook or Spyder for PyTorch

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I've installed pytorch cuda with pip and conda

when i run this command in IDLE:

```
>> import torch

>> torch.cuda.is_available()
```

I get "True",
but in Spyder or Jupyter Notebook it gives as "False" even after updating the package and conda.
The conda update of pytorch cuda was from 10.1 to 10.2

Answer (score 2):

It can be resolved by creating another environment in conda and then install torch

type:

```
>conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda
```

yourenvname is environment name

python=x.x is python version for your environment

activate the environment using:

```
>conda activate yourenvname
```

then install the PyTorch with cuda:

```
>conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

open "spyder" or "jupyter notebook"
verify if it is installed, type:

```
> import torch
> torch.cuda.is_available()
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly environment conflict, where non-GPU Pytorch has been install in previous environment. In my case, I remove all previous installed environment, and CUDA is recognize again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `pip` from within Jupyter Labs, but be sure to shutdown Jupyter Labs after install. Simply restarting the Kernel won't work.

For local Windows/Linux install:
`pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116`